# errors in stalling npm i angularx-social-login

Tags: angular, authentication, npm, installation

I am trying to authenticate with the Facebook account in my app. for that I have to install the angularx-social-login, but every time I run the command I get errors in the console. I have angular version 9, I have tried with other commands but I can't do it either.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTDU9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQv5e.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKxSb.png)

I have tried these commands:

```bash
npm install --save angularx-social-login
npm i angularx-social-login@3.5.4
npm install --save angular-9-social-login
npm i angularx-social-login
```

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "celon-dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^5.12.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^18.4.48",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.20.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-material-treetable": "^0.5.5",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1002.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.48",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.20.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "open": "^7.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I want to know what I have to do to be able to download the library

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving on the console?

Comment: Try installing a lower version. It looks like it depends on `@angular/common^12.0.0`.

Comment: the third photo